# d3: rotations and force directed layouts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rotation, force-layout

When I use rotations in my d3 applications tick function the entire application slows to a crawl.

As an example: If you uncomment the line //var angle = 0; in the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/466xJ/) it runs 20x faster.

Why is this? Are rotations just very expensive or am I doing something wrong?

```
function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  linktext.attr("transform", function(d) {
      var xDiff = d.source.x - d.target.x; 
      var yDiff = d.source.y - d.target.y; 
      var angle = Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * (180.0 / Math.PI);
      //var angle = 0;

      return "translate(" + (d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2 + ","
      + (d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2 + ")rotate(" + angle + ")"; 
    });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}
```

Note: I modified the origional jsfiddle found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ajing/Q2c2X/7/)

Comment: It's not that bad here (Chrome), but there is a noticeable difference. There's nothing you can really do about this though -- rotations of text are quite expensive as it's not a simple shape.

Comment: But it seems more related to the processing of the individual text rotations because if you set the angle to non-zero it is still quite fast.

Answer (score 2):

To track down the source of the problem, I played around with making various aspects of the text the same/different.  See [this version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/466xJ/1/).  Note that the text is different and the angle is different for each text element (so no optimization possible there) *but* the angle for each element is constant -- it doesn't change  on every tick.

The result?  Slightly sluggish at first (when there is a lot of overlap in the graph), but it quickly progresses to smooth animation under 30fps.

The same is true (with a final frame rate just slightly over 30fps) even if the text content changes every tick, as in [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/466xJ/2/).

This contradicts [the usual rule of optimizing animation](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/), that changing transformations should be more efficient than changing content.

According to the Chrome frame-rate inspector, most of the time being consumed in each repaint for [your original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/466xJ/) (which clocks in around 4fps on my computer) is being taken up by the "Paint setup" step -- i.e., in calculating each "layer" of the image.

[This blog has a quick-and-easy recap of the different steps of a repaint](http://risebird.tumblr.com/post/77825280589/gpu-youre-my-hero).  Quote:

> The following steps render the elements in the DOM into images on your screen:
>
> 1. **Trigger** - Elements are loaded into the DOM, or are modified in some way
> 2. **Recalculate Styles** - Styles are applied to elements (or re-calculated)
> 3. **Layout** - Elements are laid out geometrically, according to their positions on the screen
> 4. **Paint Setup** - The DOM is split up into render layers, which will be used to fill out the pixels for each element
> 5. **Paint** - Each layer is painted into a bitmap and is uploaded to the GPU as a texture by a software rasterizer
> 6. **Composite Layers** - The layers are composited together by the GPU and drawn to a final screen image

Normally, transformations can be done efficiently by the GPU in the final "composition" step (and a modern browser on a modern OS will automatically shift the work to the GPU).

There are two reasons why this might not be happening.  The first is simply that this optimization might not even be applied for SVG (although I'm pretty sure the default setting for the latest Chrome is to optimize SVG transforms). However, even if the browser uses some GPU optimization for SVG transforms, your GPU can only handle a limited number of layers before it runs out of memory.  With nearly 200 separately-transformed text elements (and the untransformed content layered above and below), that would be a likely bottleneck.  See [this HTML5Rocks post](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/) or [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which gives some examples of performance limits that will cancel out independent layer composition.

Whatever's going on under the hood, the end result is that your CPU, not your GPU, is calculating the rotations and layering the text together each time, and that's not efficient.

**So, what can you do about it?**

I tried optimizing the code by using a matrix transformation instead of first calculating an angle and then making the browser calculate the rotation ([see live version](http://jsfiddle.net/466xJ/6/)) ...but that didn't make a noticeable difference.  Changing to a simple skew transform instead of a rotation helped a little (frame rates up to 11fps), but that just added ugly text on top of laggy animation.

Unfortunately, it looks you're really going to have to compromise one way or the other.  Some options:

- Hide the text until the force layout has stopped, and only then calculate the rotation.  [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/466xJ/9/)

  Key code (Javascript):

  ```
  var vis = d3.select(".intgraph").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h)
      .append("svg:g")
     .on("click", function(){
         if ( force.alpha() )
             force.stop();
         else
             force.resume();
     });

  force.on("start", function(){
          vis.classed("running", true);
       })
  .on("end", function () {
      linktext.attr("transform", function (d) {
          var xDiff = d.source.x - d.target.x,
              xMid = d.source.x - xDiff / 2;
          var yDiff = d.source.y - d.target.y,
              yMid = d.source.y - yDiff / 2;
          var hyp = Math.sqrt(xDiff * xDiff + yDiff * yDiff),
              cos = xDiff / hyp,
              sin = yDiff / hyp;
          return "matrix(" + 
              [cos, sin, -sin, cos, xMid, yMid] + ")";
      });
      vis.classed("running", false);
  });
  ```

  CSS:

  ```
  .running text {
      display:none;
  }
  ```
- Show the text, but don't rotate it (optionally, rotate it in to place when the force layout stops, as above).

Answer (score 0):

When you do `//var angle = 0;` the compiler of this code probably realizes the result is meaningless and is optimized out since it never changes.  That would explain why it runs 20x faster when commenting that code.

I suspect even if you kept the translate part and removed the rotation it would be slower (though translation is clearly less computationally expensive than rotation since translations are just 3 additions compared with rotations ).

While i am not so familiar with d3.js, it would seem you are now performing translation and rotation in a function which probably gets called many times on the cpu.  (generally you would want to do that on the gpu via a shader - though im not sure if/how that would apply to d3.js).